# Problem in extracting Even Columns from 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to extract the entries of EVEN columns from the given 2D array.

The Code I have written is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [][] rearra = new int[5][3];
       int[][] arra = { {01,02,03,04,05,06},
                        {11,12,13,14,15,16},
                        {21,22,23,24,25,26},
                        {31,32,33,34,35,36},
                        {41,42,43,44,45,46}};

       rearra = method(arra);
       for(int i=0; i<rearra.length; i++)
       {
           for(int j=0; j<rearra[0].length; j++)
           System.out.println(rearra[i][j]);
       }

    }
    static int[][] method(int [][] arr)
    {
        int temp = 3;
        int [][] narra = new int[5][3];
        //int nrow=0;
        int ncol=0;

        for (int row=0; row<5; row++){
            for (int col=0; col<6; col++)
            {
                    if ((arr[row][col]) % 2 == 0) {
                        narra[row][ncol] = (arr[row][col]);
                        ncol++;
                    }
            }
        }
        return narra;
}
```

Now the output I want from this code should like this:

```
02 04 06
12 14 16
22 24 26
32 34 36
42 44 46
```

Can anyone guide me what's the problem in my program?

Comment: You test the content at position arr[row][col], you just need to test if(col % 2==0)

Comment: @lher this is Not Working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move int ncol=0; inside outer loop:

```
    for (int row=0; row<5; row++){
        int ncol=0;
        for (int col=0; col<6; col++)
        {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is generally good, but you should also strive to write clean and understandable code. I will provide you with example that works for any array size and prints it nicely.

- Your three main actions were all extracted into methods of their own, and thanks to that you can run it with any array.
- Variable names have been replaced with meaningful ones so other people (and you sometimes in the future) can better understand what is going on.
- Method for extracting even columns checks the length of each row, which needs not to be the same for all rows.
- It works by checking if column index is even and if so, inserts into appropriate place in the new array.

I hope you will improve your skills by analyzing this example, good luck!

Full code:

```
public class ArrayExample {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = initializeArray();
        int[][] evenColumnsOnly = getEvenColumns(arr);
        printArray(evenColumnsOnly);
    }

    static int[][] initializeArray() {
        int[][] arr = { {01,02,03,04,05,06},
                        {11,12,13,14,15,16},
                        {21,22,23,24,25,26},
                        {31,32,33,34,35,36},
                        {41,42,43,44,45,46}};
        return arr;
    }

    static void printArray(int[][] arrayToPrint) {
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayToPrint.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < arrayToPrint[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%d\t", arrayToPrint[i][j]));
            }
            System.out.println();
        } 
    }

    static int[][] getEvenColumns(int [][] arr)
    {
        int [][] evenColumnsOnlyArray = new int[arr.length][];

        for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
            int rowSize = arr[row].length / 2;
            evenColumnsOnlyArray[row] = new int[rowSize];

            for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++) {
                if(col % 2 == 0  && col / 2 < rowSize) {
                    evenColumnsOnlyArray[row][col / 2] = arr[row][col];
                }
            }
        }

        return evenColumnsOnlyArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks brother for helping me... As I have just started learning Java, so don't know how to work professionally. But I will definitely improve my programming skills. Again Thank You!